# with the same station number (reference number), how to compare a record with that of 2 hours ago

Tags: sql-server

I have time-series data for a number of gauging stations and developed methodology, described below to determine whether river level is rising, steady or falling.

**Method:**
grab the oldest value within a time frame such as two hours and compares that value with the latest using the tolerance method of within a tolerance range of each, such as 0.5 cm then the site is 'steady'. If the latest value is above the tolerance then the tendency is 'rising' and if below then it is 'falling'.

How do I transfer the methodology into `#T-SQL?`

The date set format is like Site, Value and DT

```
Site     Value       DT
12345678    0   13/01/2019 0:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 1:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 2:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 3:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 4:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 5:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 6:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 7:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 8:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 9:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 10:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 11:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 13:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 14:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 16:00
12345678    0   13/01/2019 17:00
12345678   0.05 13/01/2019 17:57     
12345678   0.15 13/01/2019 17:57     
12345678   0.20 13/01/2019 17:58     
12345678   0.25 13/01/2019 17:58     
12345678   0.30 13/01/2019 17:59     
12345678   0.35 13/01/2019 17:59     
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 18:00            
12345678   0.50 13/01/2019 18:01     
12345678   0.55 13/01/2019 18:03     
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 19:00     
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 20:00     
12345678   0.20 13/01/2019 21:00     
12345678   0.10 13/01/2019 22:00          
12345678    0   13/01/2019 23:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 0:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 1:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 2:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 3:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 4:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 5:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 6:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 7:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 8:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 9:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 10:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 11:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 12:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 13:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 14:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 15:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 16:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 17:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 18:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 19:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 20:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 21:00
12345678    0   14/01/2019 22:00
```

I have tried to use `DATEADD` and `BETWEEN` to find the oldest value within two hours without success.

Here is an expected output data set (manually generated). The reason why the tendency at 13/01/2019 17:57 is rising is because firstly it compares the oldest value within a time frame of two hours, which is 13/01/2019 16:00 and the value of 0, with itself(0.5) and also the it exceeds the tolerance of 0.5 (0.5-0=0.5) This two factors contributes the result of tendency as Rising. On 13/01/2019 20:00, the value reached 0.40 which is the same as two hours ago (18:00) and less than the difference of 0.5, resulting in Steady. On 13/01/2019 21:00, the tendency is falling because of the comparison between that and the value at 19:00 (0.4) plus the difference is more than 0.5.

```
Site     Value       DT              Tendency
12345678    0   13/01/2019 0:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 1:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 2:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 3:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 4:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 5:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 6:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 7:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 8:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 9:00      Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 10:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 11:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 13:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 14:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 16:00     Steady
12345678    0   13/01/2019 17:00     Steady
12345678   0.05 13/01/2019 17:57     Rising
12345678   0.15 13/01/2019 17:57     Rising
12345678   0.20 13/01/2019 17:58     Rising
12345678   0.25 13/01/2019 17:58     Rising
12345678   0.30 13/01/2019 17:59     Rising
12345678   0.35 13/01/2019 17:59     Rising
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 18:00     Rising
12345678   0.50 13/01/2019 18:01     Rising
12345678   0.55 13/01/2019 18:03     Rising
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 19:00     Rising
12345678   0.40 13/01/2019 20:00     Steady
12345678   0.20 13/01/2019 21:00     Falling
12345678   0.10 13/01/2019 22:00     Falling
```

Comment: Can you include what your expected output would look like?

Comment: the output I expect is to the columns of Site,Value and DT, plus tendency (i.e. falling, steady and rising ) determined by the methodology above

Comment: YuChun I just don't understand what you're after well enough to give a good answer. If you can provide a mock up of the output data set (similar to how you did with the raw data), I might be able to fine tune my answer.

Comment: I put the expected output data set above. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number` going in alternating directions to get the first and last values:

```
declare @Now datetime = getdate()

select 
    CurrentValue = max(iif(DescRID = 1, Value, null)),
    PastValue =  max(iif(AscRID = 1, Value, null))
from 
(
    select 
        AscRID = row_number() over( order by Dt),
        DescRID = row_number() over (order by Dt desc),
        Value
    from #data
    where Dt >= dateadd(hour, -2, @Now)
) a
where AscRID = 1 
    or DescRID = 1
```

Comment: you are using getdate() for the value just coming. however, I hope to deal with some historical data as well. the solution seems not to be able to do it. do you have other suggested code?

Comment: YiChun this is why I was hoping to get an example of your expected output data. To do exactly one period is much simple than doing all of them at once, and I'm not sure if thats what you're after. Can you include some example output data in your OP (like you did with the input data) to clarify things?

Comment: I put the expected output data set above. Please let me know if anything needs to be clarfied